type classes act as interfaces (??)
After reading about type classes in Haskell, I thought them as like Java interfaces
You define a set of methods in your type class (Num) and any data/newtype(Foo) declared type, if it wants to be part of the type class, must implement all the methods of that type class.
But what is the use of this ?
How does this relates to polymorphism ?
Is it parametric poly or ad-hoc poly ?
This is how the Num type class is defined in ghci
type Num :: * -> Constraint
class Num a where
  (+) :: a -> a -> a
  (-) :: a -> a -> a
  (*) :: a -> a -> a
  negate :: a -> a
  abs :: a -> a
  signum :: a -> a
  fromInteger :: Integer -> a
  {-# MINIMAL (+), (*), abs, signum, fromInteger, (negate | (-)) #-}
    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
instance Num Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
instance Num Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
...

Firstly, what does the first type Num :: * -> Constraint means (?)
After, it saying that, if a type a wants to be get constraint/part-of Num, it should implement the following functions.
Below it shows some instances of this type class as Double, Float
This looks like java interfaces.
So, for Foo to be a member of this Num
We need to do something like
instance Num Foo where 
  (+) foo1 foo2 = foo1
   ...

But What is the use of it (?)
I understand how they are defined

Please read this (disclaimer: shameless plug)

The type Num :: * -> Constraint part shows the kind of Num. It means, roughly, "Num is a monoparametric type class". Kinds are, in a way, types of types.

"What is the use of it?" This way we can define overloaded functions, so that 1 + length myList and 1 + sin(pi/3.0) both make sense, despite length myList and sin(pi/3.0) being of different types. In the first case, + defined in the Int instance is used, and in the second case, + defined in the Double instance is used.

@n.m.couldbeanAI now I see, we are trying to implement "generics" (?)

"implement "generics"" --- No, not at all.

"Generics" is another name for parametric polymorphism. Type classes provide ad hoc polymorphism.

You say they seem like Java interfaces, and object they seem pointless. Do you have the same objection to Java interfaces, that they seem pointless to you? If not, what motivates these two apparently opposed attitudes?

my question should have been, how are interfaces helpful in programming

See also How to make ad-hoc polymorphism less ad hoc (Wadler & Blott, 1989)

First of all the kind signature * -> Constraint means that Num is something that takes a type (*) and returns a Constraint.
A Constraint is an interface, namely a contract that a type has to satisfy, in the form of implementing some methods.
Polymorphism is related to this because you can use constraints to write functions which are generic over types, but with some more fine-grained requirements. For example: suppose you have a function that wants to find an element in a list. The type might be
indexOf :: a -> [a] -> Int

where the returned type is the position and the type variable a is the type of the object and the list. But wait... in any implementation of this method, at some point, I will have to compare x :: a with an element in as :: [a], using =. So it's not really generic on a, we need to impose a Constraint that says "a must implement some notion of equality with the = operator". Then the type signature becomes
indexOf :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int

The => is not like the function arrow, it's more like saying "Provided the constraint Eq a is satisfied then ..."

=> is, in a way, somewhat like a function arrow. If you squint hard enough, it means "this is a function that (implicitly) receives an instance (a dictionary of methods, that is) of Eq a.

I believe Type is now the preferred "spelling" of *.

I would add one slight cautionary comment to @n.m.couldbeanAI's, which is that one implementation technique for typeclasses is to treat => like a dictionary function. Certainly it's the technique used by GHC, practically speaking the only Haskell implementation in current use. In that sense, thinking of it like a function is a good intuition pump. But, strictly speaking, that's not what it means -- its meaning is more abstract.
